# substring temperature in shell script

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to get the tempreture of the machine but when I use the following command:

```
sensors | awk '/thermistor/ && /temp5/ {print $2}'|awk 'sub("/+/","",$1) sub("/.0°C/","",4$)'
```

it give me for example `+26.0°C` I want the output to be 26 I tried the fllowing and it gave me the same result

```
sensors | awk '/thermistor/ && /temp5/ {print $2}'|awk 'gsub("/+","") gsub("/.0°C","")'
```

please advise thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gsub command should be,

```
echo '+26.0°C' | awk '{gsub(/\+|\.0°C/, "")}1'
```

`+` , `.` are special char in regex. You must escape that inorder to match lietral character of those. And also you must write the regex pattern within forward slash delimiters.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/YEQlhA)

Answer (score 1):

This `gsub` seems to be the problem:

```
gsub("/.0°C","");
```

as first argument is an invalid regex string.

Replace it by:

```
gsub(/\.0°C/,"");
```